# Search Console detects Category Pagination data as Duplicate Meta Description

Tags: seo

Google Search Console detects Category Pagination data up Duplicate Meta Description. Duplicate meta descriptions data is the category description that I have provided, which shows up in every pages.

The error is of Duplicate meta descriptions under HTML Improvements.

The better way I can explain this problem is by sharing the blog links directly. The problem is with the following page -

https://technosamigos.com/category/android/root/page/6/
https://technosamigos.com/category/android/root/page/7/

There are few more errors of same kind.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The option I would use is to add noindex to all pages except the first one.

If you are using an SEO plugin this should be an option.

Otherwise, something like this might work if used in a hook:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );

if( $paged >= 2 )
  echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to use a canonical URL for your paginated pages to tell search engines which page you want in your results.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://technosamigos.com/category/android/root/">
```

You can also use `rel="next"` and `rel="prev"` to show your category pagination.

This this article for more information: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en